# Tesseract ORC not reading clear text cutting from image

Tags: c++, opencv, ocr, tesseract

I'm having trouble with reading number from document using Tesseract OCR.

I have cut text from the document. And using Tesseract OCR to read it. But nothing print in the command line.

I have test it with simple document white background and black number. It work perfect.

This is my code to detect number:

```
orc->SetImage(source.data, source.size().width, source.size().height, source.channels(), 
source.step1());
QString outText = QString::fromUtf8(orc->GetUTF8Text());
if (outText != "")
    qDebug() << outText;
```

And this is my picture:

[image]

Can someone tell me where i'm wrong ?

Comment: Try to binarize your image using various thresholding options available in opencv including OTSU, adaptive thresholding, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know how to do it in c++. But I can get the numbers using this code in python. I think the key is processing in hsv color mode.

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pytesseract

img = cv2.imread("djwtV.png", cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
img = cv2.resize(img, None, fx=3, fy=3)
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

upper = np.array([255, 255, 150])
lower = np.array([0, 0, 0])
mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower, upper)
mask = cv2.bitwise_not(mask)

custom_config = r'-l eng --oem 3 --psm 6 -c tessedit_char_whitelist="0123456789,"'
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(mask, config=custom_config)
print("Detected: ", text)

cv2.imshow("img", img)
cv2.imshow("mask", mask)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The result

```
Detected:  4,691,613
```

And if you change the code into this

```
upper = np.array([255, 255, 125])

custom_config = r'-l jpn --oem 3 --psm 6 '
```

You will get this

```
Detected:  | 預り金 計①(a+b+c) |  4.691.613
```

Comment: I have convert this to c++ code and it work perfectly. Thanks